# Force SQL Server to use CA certificate

Tags: sql-server, ssl, dns

I have imported an SSL certificate from entrust.  The certificate is visible in IIS and the site can be accessed with SSL so I know the certificate is good.

However i want to use the certificate to encrypt the connection to the sql server.  The certificate is not shown in sql config manager as i believe the issued to name doesn't match my host name.

My server name is for example zserver.z1 but i access the server with a dns name of dbserver.company.net.  As i will be accessing the server with the dns name, is it possible to force the certificate?

When i created the certificate request, i did specify the dns name as my server name but it doesnt show it on the certificate.  Maybe i should contact entrust, but i thought there may be a registry fix out there hopefully!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately i could not make sql read the other certificate, i was able to reapply for certificate without charges for the local server address and this is now viewable in sql config manager.